# What's the best way to get Facebook friends using Graph API today?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to make an "invite friends" screen on my app. I already searched for Send Dialog, Invitable Friends (which apparently doesn't work for me) and Taggable Friends. Nothing work very well.

I just want a good way to send some kind of notification to my friends who doesn't use my app yet.

Is there any way?

Also, how Kiwi made it?

Answer (score 1):

Everything you need to know about inviting friends to your App can be found here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/faq#friend_invite